# Add-on Publish missing add-on-type "Gmail"

Tags: gmail-addons

I am running a Gmail add-on and now would like to publish this Add-on from the AppsScript editor.

Why does the add-on-type only show "Google Docs,..." but no Gmail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Google's official documentation on how to publish an app https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/how-tos/publish#publish_an_add-on. If it's a private app to be used within your domain you can publish it yourself otherwise you have to submit it for review.

Comment: i found this https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdQD9F5TXZvlpQcY1I6fvaZqLvULG1THhou3y5IpRRwjgwZYg/viewform and now a review by Google started.

Comment: @Malte Did you ever got an answer from Google?